# how to set screen size in android for libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on libGDX project. I want to set the screen size to 480x800.
In desktop version we can use

```
config.Width() = 480;
config.Height() = 800;
```

in DesktopLauncher class. It works on desktop, but not on android. I want to set the screen at 480x800 so it will work on android device as well. Right now my screen looks like following. 
[image]

How can I solve this issue?
Note: I have already used following code

```
    OrthographicCamera camera; 
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
 camera.setToOrtho(false, GameInfo.SCREEN_WIDTH, GameInfo.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(game.getCamera().combined);
```

It works, but it's not a permanant solution. Because, if I want to move the screen I need to set up another orthographicCamera and that doesn't work out at all. Is there any command like there is in DesktopLauncher class?

Comment: Not clear on what you're actually asking, and why you're bringing up the DesktopLauncher class. That has nothing to do with moving the view, only setting the dimensions of the window. Since phone games are always full-screen, that's irrelevant. You can't change the dimensions of the physical hardware of the phone or its resolution.

Comment: Actually if I play it on desktop simulator then using the config.width works(i.e. screen becomes full size. covers entire emulator area). But as can be seen in the photo, the same thing doesn't happen for connected android device. As you can see the image doesn't get resized automatically. For that reason I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move screen, you can change the position of your camera.

```
Sprite man;

private void render(float delta){

    //...
    camera.translate(man.getX(),man.getY());
    camera.update();

}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll use it in my next project and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is for a long time ago, I will answer it anyway.

As you know for every screen in LibGDX you must implements Screen and override all of the methods.

for set screen size properly for all devices just use resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gameViewport.update(width, height);
}
```

the 'gameViewport' already must be defined.